# Why is it invalid when setting the background color for ul tag?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, frontend

I'm using ul tag to create a dropdown in vue, but I don't know why setting the background doesn't work.I haven't set the style of li tag.

HTML

```html
    <div
      class="lang-dropdown"
      @mouseover="langActive = true"
      @mouseleave="langActive = false"
    >
      <ul>
        <li v-for="k in [1, 2, 3]" class="lang-option"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

SCSS

```
  .lang-dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 4;
    background: transparent;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding-top: 8px;
    min-width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    ul {
      list-style: none;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      border-radius: 15px;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      background: black;
      color: #2c3e50;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  }
```

[image: looks like]

Comment: I [cannot reproduce](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/qBogveO).

Answer (score 0):

I think that white area is another white element (for example an absolute element) that is positioned on the top layer of `ul`

Comment: There is no absolute position element other than lang-dropdown

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason, the absolute position element was obscured by the upper div.

Comment: You could provide more details on that to help other users with similar problems - you didn't put the upper div code on the question, neither given details on what you actually did to solve your issue you could also mark the question as answered, to show there is a solution to the question...